# EF Core optimize query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have some important delay when displaying data on an asp.net web site and I'm searching for ways to optimize them.
Here is my (simplified) data model for three tables :

```
 public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Contact = new HashSet<Contact>();
        Event = new HashSet<Evenement>();
        Mission = new HashSet<Mission>();
    }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Event { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mission> Mission { get; set; }
}
public partial class Mission
{
    public Mission()
    {
        Event = new HashSet<Event>();
    }

    public int MissionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Evenement> Event{ get; set; }
}
public partial class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        Event = new HashSet<Event>();
        Mission = new HashSet<Mission>();
    }

    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Event { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mission> Mission { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have Companies. Each Company can have several contacts and several missions.
One mission has one company and one contact linked to.
An event can be linked to a company, a contact and a mission (all combination is possible, ex. : an event is linked to a company and a mission but with no contact...)

When displaying a company in the web site,  I do the following linq request :

```
Company = await _context.Company
            .Include(s => s.Contact)
            .Include(s => s.Mission)
            .Include(s => s.Event).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CompanyId == id);
```

This query is so long when having quite few events and missions linked to the company I want to display.
When I delete ".Include(s => s.Mission)" statement, every thing goes fast.
Any idea is welcome, thank you for your help !

Comment: What *do* you want to display? Do you need all the related classes *and* events? Loading 1000 events is always going to be slower than loading none or just 1

Comment: @trinalbadger587 ????? That's LINQ in C# using EF Core, not SQL

Comment: How many missions and events are there for this company? Do the tables have the proper indexes? Is `CompanyId` in the `Missions` table indexed? Is `MissionId` in `Events` indexed?

Comment: thank you for your answers. I want to display company informations : in this page, I have three tab : one for the company's missions, one for its events and one for its contact

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : yes : each ID (foreign key) has its own index

Comment: For an exemple : my test database store a company linked to 250 events and 13 missions. It takes 20sec to display that in "full" localhost (db and iis)

Comment: That's really slow. That's not a lot of data. In any case, you can't display all that data in a single page. The browser itself will be slow to render so much data that isn't visible anyway. Use paging and load only what you can display in a single page instead

Comment: How large are these classes in reality? Using slim projections instead of querying large classes usually makes a huge difference. Even then, 20s seems too long if everything is indexed well. Check the query plan.

Comment: Yes, it's so slow ! The "Detail Company web page" has pagination for mission , event and contact. It's a js paging, client side. It can be optimized, but for onaly 250 items... the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @Negatonrax, try to add `.AsSplitQuery()`. It should persevere Cartesian Explosion.

Comment: @GertArnold : if by "large" you are asking for number of fields in each tables, consider there is 20 fields in company, 6 in event, 10 in contact  and 15 in mission

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : yes, we have eard about it. Our project is in EF Core 3.1. I just wanted to know if I could have a solution vbefore migrate in ef core 5.0 to have a try...

Comment: @Negatonrax, get SQL query generated by EF and run in SQL Server Management Studio. And check how many records are returned by this query. This is the answer.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv : thank you. I did not think about this way "so simple" ! I will try it very fast

Comment: Also you can load Missions separately. `context.Entity(company).Collection(s => s.Mission).Load()`